# .Net DNA/Codon Parser

Tags: bioinformatics

Does anyone know of an .NET (C#,VB.NET, maybe F#) DNA parser?  If not I will probably make one, it doesn't seem like it would be hard.  My general idea was to generate something that would report the codon biases and go back and adjust the bias for engineering.

I realize the later part is a bit specific, but if anyone knew about an open .NET program that annualized/parsed the codon bias, I'd be interested.

Thanks.

Comment: Something like [this](https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/bio/mbf.aspx)?  I know nothing about .NET.

Comment: Maybe, I'm going to check it out.  I solid library would do the trick.

Comment: @amory Looks like it might.  I don't know how I missed that in my searching

Comment: Cool.  Posted an answer for the sake of statistics.

Comment: If you're thinking of entering bioinformatics, I strongly urge you to use a Unix/Linux platform and not .NET or other MS tools. It will make your life much much easier.

Comment: What's cool about bioinformatics is that it has both a father and a mother !

Comment: @terdon oh I agree. My real entry into programming was with R on Debian, and I am a fan of BioPup, but I don't think that's being developed anymore.  The only reason I'm interested now, is to throw something into an already existing WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much (read: anything) about the [.NET framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) but a little search turned up [Microsoft's .NET Bio](https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/bio/mbf.aspx):

> .NET Bio (formerly Microsoft Biology Foundation [MBF]) is a language-neutral bioinformatics toolkit built as an extension to the Microsoft .NET Framework—initially aimed at the area of Genomics research. Currently, it implements a range of parsers for common bioinformatics file formats; a range of algorithms for manipulating DNA, RNA, and protein sequences; and a set of connectors to biological web services such as NCBI BLAST.

Free (as in beer) and open source!  And from [this](http://julmar.com/blog/mark/?p=143) it looks pretty cool.